# Ошибка при запуске контейнера

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

> Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting >container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"
>   Error: failed to start containers: namename

Пытлася запустить контейнер с именем "namename". использовал команду `docker start namename`

Статус контейнера отмечен как созданный

Comment: Все команды выполняю от рута

Comment: docker run -it namename bash

Comment: `docker run -it namename bash` просто создает новый контейнер со статусом:  created((( @a.arsenenko

Comment: просто нужно было создать контейнеры с **sh**